# iOS 14 how to use "Open Wallet" and "Open Apple Card card" in automation and script

Tags: ios, script, automation

Does anyone have an example or some pointers on using iOS 14 automation, shortcuts and scripting to open the wallet app and retrieve data from Apple Card?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot retrieve data directly using Shortcuts or Automation.

If you would like to retrieve data, you could use the "Open Apple Card card" process to open the card. Then, the user should export a statement and send it back to an Application or to be processed by a Shortcut.

The export options are CSV, OFX, QFX, and QBO - and they can be done on a month-by-month basis.